# Maintain stock_on_quantity on item_master table whenever an item is purchased or sold

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, datatrigger, database-trigger, eventtrigger

Minimum 3 stocks in item_master table should be maintained.

Table: item_master

```
create table item_master
(
    item_no number(5) primary key,
    name varchar(10),
    stock_on_hand number(5) default 0
);
```

Table: item_detail

```
create table item_detail
(
    item_no number(5) references item_master,
    operation varchar(10) check(operation in('Sales','Purchase')),
    quantity number(5)
);


insert into item_master values(101,'Chair',5);
insert into item_master values(102,'Sofa',4);
insert into item_master values(103,'Table',6);
```

I have written this trigger for maintaining minimum 3 stocks.

```
    create or replace trigger tristk
    before insert or update or delete on item_master
    for each row
    declare 
        stk number(5);
    begin
select stock_on_hand into stk from item_master where item_no = :new.item_no;

        if(stk<=3) then 
            raise_application_error(-20000,'Not enough stock');    
        end if;
    end;
    /
```

I have written Another trigger to automatically update item_master whenever I insert or update or delete in item_detail

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER triitem AFTER
    INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON item_detail
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE item_master
    SET
        stock_on_hand =
            CASE :new.operation
                WHEN 'Sales'      THEN stock_on_hand -:new.quantity
                WHEN 'Purchase'   THEN stock_on_hand +:new.quantity
            END
    WHERE item_no =:new.item_no;
END;
/
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: My trigger is not working